# how to get value(python)

Tags: python, json, string, web-crawler

```
'window.__additionalDataLoaded(\'/p/CI3mtIABQDO/\',{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"2465609547742773454","shortcode":"CI3mtIABQDO","dimensions":{"height":1316,"width":1080},"gating_info":null,"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"sensitivity_friction_info":null,"sharing_friction_info":{"should_have_sharing_friction":false,"bloks_app_url":null},"media_overlay_info":null,"media_preview":"ACIqqXC5hJ/z1rKUEnjrWzOP9Gb2x/NapWDKjsz9lOB6n0B7f5FT0K6lqeJAhMeS4PIweP8APX/61ZjFifmOfeukURFPlOVPTjr7H0welYkZVUK9W7nGfT/69JMGVjjsKKsNHkn6+lFO4jQc7rZh14/+JqGCMQqOVDvgnIyw9h2A9See1SJMifKpH0HPtULSSMOVJX5iRt4xn1/maQy0bl43XDIQSchFGPQlgOT6/qKrNAVkyMYYZ3Doc+2eOe3FEbRh9w6N1GPu88Y+9/Lp3qS8RHVXICgenQZ7cevWgCqzEE9Dz1oqsTzweO1FMRIAR07U2WZnA3EkD/OPpViLv9DUHZv92kMfbuQQE6ueAexx79vSrTyOMqTz6A5Ax+A5/lVdeQD7f41IKLjsR+WKKloqSj//2Q==","display_url":"https://scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/131072573_200156958440171_7958560074248767851_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com\\u0026_nc_cat=1\\u0026_nc_ohc=yxooq3IfF44AX9mIzGL\\u0026tp=1\\u0026oh=a4ba1164d97a86464b2a0bbb4d7ce19c\\u0026oe=6002C769","display_resources":[{"src":"https://scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/131072573_200156958440171_7958560074248767851_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com\\u0026_nc_cat=1\\u0026_nc_ohc=yxooq3IfF44AX9mIzGL\\u0026tp=1\\u0026oh=040a7b7d5fda5772ad0668d27ae2333b\\u0026oe=6003172E","config_width":640,"config_height":780},{"src":"https://scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p750x750/131072573_200156958440171_7958560074248767851_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com\\u0026_nc_cat=1\\u0026_nc_ohc=yxooq3IfF44AX9mIzGL\\u0026tp=1\\u0026oh=84141972d27eba9381408204011b3109\\u0026oe=600594EA","config_width":750,"config_height":914},{"src":"https://scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/131072573_200156958440171_7958560074248767851_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-gmp1-1.cdninstagram.com\\u0026_nc_cat=1\\u0026_nc_ohc=yxooq3IfF44AX9mIzGL\\u0026tp=1\\u0026oh=a4ba1164d97a86464b2a0bbb4d7ce19c\\u0026oe=6002C769","config_width":1080,"config_height":1316}],"accessibility_caption":"Photo by Fashion Selection \\ud83e\\udd84\\ud83d\\udc95 on December 16, 2020. \\uc0ac\\uc9c4 \\uc124\\uba85\\uc774 \\uc5c6\\uc2b5\\ub2c8\\ub2e4..","is_video":false,"tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiM2Y1NDUzZjJjNmFkNGZmM2FkZDEyZDNiMTBjYWMwNmEyNDY1NjA5NTQ3NzQyNzczNDU0Iiwic2VydmVyX3Rva2VuIjoiMTYwODE4MTQ2Mjg2NnwyNDY1NjA5NTQ3NzQyNzczNDU0fDQ0NzQ2NDA2ODk5fGI2ZmY3Y2Q5NTA5NjQ4Njk3ZTA5MzI0OWU0ZWU4OTU3ZDQ3N2EwZDU4YmZiYTJiNDVkYzIyYmM4NmFkOWU1NTEifSwic2lnbmF0dXJlIjoiIn0=","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"Yes or No? \\ud83d\\ude0d"}}]},"caption_is_edited":false,"has_ranked_comments":true,"edge_media_to_parent_comment":{"count":175,"page_info".........(type=str)
```

In above string
I want to find `count:175` in `edge_media_to_parent_comment:{count:175}`
please help

Comment: This is not just a json. You can parse it to use regex, Google the "python regex match"

Comment: What are you using selenium or requests?

Comment: I'm using selenium

Comment: Can you provide me link to that website?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/CI3mtIABQDO/
here it is

Comment: Original https://www.instagram.com/p/CI3mtIABQDO/?__a=1
I tried to request a page, but I got a response[429] error, so I was forced to go to selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get your work done without any regex. And yes you were accessing wrong js object, you have to access `window._sharedData`

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("Driver's path")
URL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CI3mtIABQDO/"
driver.get(URL)   

data = driver.execute_script('return window._sharedData')  #it will return that js object as python dictionary stored in data variable

#You can access data using access operator 

count = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_parent_comment']['count']

print(count)
```

Above returned `182` to me.

If you want to just access the whole object than you may use below code, it will return entire dict object inside `edge_media_to_parent_comment` attribute

```
count = data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_parent_comment']
```

Comment: I wanted to get it in json form like this without using regex. Thank you for always!

Comment: When I ran the code 10 minutes ago, I noticed that 182 came out, but now I get another ```KeyError:'graphql'``` What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're using same URL over and over with the same IP which causes rate-limiting and instagram is asking you to login. You should see the process graphically without setting browser to headless

Comment: I didn't understand well. How to solve it?

Comment: If you send too many request to instagram's server with same IP address within some intervals of time. It will detect your IP and start to redirect you to login page,every single time you make a request. Its the rate-limiting feature of instagram to prevent DDoS attack. You can see all the process if your browser is not running in headless mode,it'll help you to debug the code. One of the solution will be to use proxy every time you make a request, you can even change headers so you can create a new identity for every request

Comment: If I'm not excused, can you tell me how to use a proxy?
I do not understand even if I search:(

Comment: Sure read from [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium), it has represented the code in simplest way. I know web scraping is headache sometimes so you can ping me if you didn't understood this, without any hesitation at any time :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```py
import re
m = '<WHATEVER YOUR STRING IS>'
ss = re.findall(r'edge_media_to_parent_comment.*(\"count\"):(\d+)', m)
if len(ss) > 0:
  # do whatever you want to do
  ...
```

Comment: answer = [('"count"', '111088')]
what's wrong?

Comment: could you paste the string, maybe we need to tweak the regular expression

Comment: String is too long to be truncated.
When I use re.search I get these results
```ss = re.search(r'edge_media_to_parent_comment.*(\"count\"):(\d)', str(script))```
ss[0]=
```<re.Match object; span=(2998, 17220), match='edge_media_to_parent_comment":{"count":17,"page_i>```

Comment: The answer comes this far
```"edge_followed_by":{"count":111088'```
It was too long, so I used only the very end

Comment: if you are certain that the first thing that comes within `edge_media_to_parent_comment` is `count`, you could try this:

`ss = re.findall(r'edge_media_to_parent_comment\"\s*:{(\"count\"):(\d+)', str(script))`

Comment: succeded. Really thankful. But how did \s become the right answer?